# Link in comment with spaces in URL

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I couldn't get the link tag to work in a comment on Stack Overflow. Maybe because the URL has spaces in it?

This is what I tried:

```
[website](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java Interop-The Dot special form)
```

It might also be helpful to preview comments in the same fashion that questions are previewed.

Comment: Well this doesn't work in the question body either. You will have to replace the spaces with `%20`s.

Comment: The URL should be valid. You can use online tool such as [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to encode the value after "?" or "#" in the URL.

Comment: My bad I copied the URL from Chrome.  Safari escapes the spaces...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is "[website](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-The%20Dot%20special%20form)" what you wanted? Just use "%20" instead of white space (" ") in the URL:

> http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-The%20Dot%20special%20form

@ShadowWizard has suggested [a useful site for URL encoding (and decoding)](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) all sorts of potentially problematic symbols (also including `:`, `/`, `&`, `#`, `%`, `@`, crazy combinations thereof, etc....) Just be sure to avoid encoding the functional symbols your browser needs to read as-is instead of decoding.

IMHO, the five-minute window for editing comments is plenty. If you really want to change your comment after the edit window closes, you can delete it and post a new one. Probably wiser to stick with a workaround than to ask for a UI overhaul to enhance comments on SE, which de-emphasizes comments in general.